# How to remove a decimal but retain the value of the number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a "column of numbers", say 342.21 into 34221 with a number of leading zeroes. Expected end result would be 0000000000034221. What specific format or code should I use in vba to get this?

I am trying to convert an excel file to text file using vba. The field length for the end result is fix at 16 digits and length for the "column of numbers" may vary. Hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value * 100,"0000000000000000")
```

Comment: @BlairWaldorf please mark the one that worked for you, the one you ended up using as the correct one by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You mention a string:

```
=RIGHT("0000000000000000"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",""),16)
```

Will result in a string that will export to csv includiong the `0`s

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Did yours and JNevill's code and it worked. However, for values with 0 decimals, such as 1.00, the result came out as "0000000000000001".

Answer (score 2):

Since you are converting to a string, we can just treat your number value as a string.

Assuming your number is stored in variable `num`:

```
outputnumber = String(16 - (Len(num) - 1), "0") & Replace(num, ".", "")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Did yours and cybernetic.nomad's code and it worked. However, for values with 0 decimals, such as 1.00, the result came out as "0000000000000001".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Custom Format type: `0000000000000000` (That's 16 zeroes)

Then in the cell, you could do `=A1*100` assuming `A1` has `342.21`.

[image]

(Edit: Sorry, missed the VBA tag. The above doesn't use VBA).

Comment: Also when sending to the csv, it will send the value not the formatted version

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a simplified code:

```
    Amount = (.Cells(iRow,6)) - where I store my values
    Amount = Format(Amount*100, "0000000000000000")
```

Thank you so much for the help guys! :)